# Child Routes Complaining About Missing Route Config

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to do a master / detail type view in my Angular2 application. In my main app component, I have the following routes defined:

```
@Routes([
    { path: '/',  component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '/brands/:brandId/...', component: BrandShowComponent },
    { path: '/brands', component: BrandListComponent }
])
```

I can navigate just fine to `/brands` where I show a list of Brands. When selecting a specific Brand, I'm trying to show the details of said Brand. In addition, the `BrandShowComponent` will also have child routes. Note the `...` in the above route config. In `BrandShowComponent` I've defined a child route like so:

```
@Routes([
    { path: '/regions', component: RegionListComponent }
])
```

And I've added a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to the template for `BrandShowComponent`.

As I said, I can view the list of brands, but when I click on a specific brand, I get the following error in the console:

`browser_adapter.ts:78 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Component 'BrandListComponent' does not have route configuration`

I want `BrandShowComponent` to be the `master`, not `BrandListComponent`. I'm unsure what I might have configured incorrectly to make Angular think otherwise. Or if I'm getting bit by a `RC` issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in the current router.

Sort the routes so that the most significant came first:

```
@Routes([
    { path: '/brands/:brandId/...', component: BrandShowComponent },
    { path: '/brands', component: BrandListComponent }
    { path: '/',  component: HomeComponent },
])
```

Comment: I thought that also, but not in this case. I changed my `@Routes` as you suggested and I still get the same error.

Comment: What causes the error? Routerlink, page reload with deep link, `router.navigate()`?. I just saw `/...`. That needs to be removed in the new RC router because it is not a thing anymore.

Comment: The error is caused when I click a routerLink for `/brands/:brandId` from the `BrandListComponent`. When I go to BrandShowComponent, I have a sidebar with a list of routerLinks that I want to display on the BrandShowComponent as children, but I'd like the route updated in the URL. So `/brands/123/regions` and `/brands/123/departments`, etc. Keeping the sidebar in place.

Comment: How does the routerlink look like exactly? Have you tried without `/...` already?

Comment: `[routerLink]="['/brands/' + brand.id]"` - yes, I removed the `/...` and I can get to the show page again, but now I'm unsure how to handle the master/detail aspect. So maybe my question is obsolete. All the google-fu still suggests using `/...` with child routes. Unsure how to do that in `RC.1` now.

Comment: Just use child routes as before but don't add anything special like `/...`.

Comment: Okay, so that works in terms of the route, but it is replacing the entire `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and I want to, on a route, "embed" a component. Alternatively I could make my sidebar a component and put it on every template where I need it. But that isn't ideal. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "replacing the entire router-outlet". You **can have** child routes as before. The new router still has several issues and will be improved soon.

Comment: Thanks. I'm talking about standard master/detail. Master on the left sidebar and showing child details on the right as I click links. But I want the route in the URL to change too. Hence the need for child routes to work as described https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/25/angular-2-series-part-4-component-router-in-depth/